# Cannot find main class in Minecraft bukkit plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to learn how to write minecraft plugins however I am having a bit of a problem getting started, when I try and run the exported plugin I get a main class not found error. I have already tried moving the plugin.yml file, checked all parts were exported and renaming classes etc to no avail. Have also read existing questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main:

```
package me.raultechsupport.helloworld;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import me.raultechsupport.helloworld.commands.hellocommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new hellocommand(this);
    }
}
```

hellocommand:

```
package me.raultechsupport.helloworld.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import me.raultechsupport.helloworld.Main;

public class hellocommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Main plugin;

    public hellocommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] arg3) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if (p.hasPermission("hello.use")) {
            p.sendMessage("Hi!");
            return true;
        } else {
            p.sendMessage("You do not have permission to execute this command!");
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

plugin.yml:

```
name: HelloWorld
version: 1.0
author: RaulTechSupport
main: me.raultechsupport.helloworld.Main
description: Hello.

commands:
  hello:
    aliases: [hi]
    description: Hi!
```

The console error:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Cannot find main class `me.raultechsupport.helloworld.Main' [11:36:00 ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins/HelloWorld.jar' in folder 'plugins' at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:137) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082] at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:81) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082] at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:305) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:397) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:389) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:264) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:1070) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:291) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.raultechsupport.helloworld.Main
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:183) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:111) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:79) ~[patched_1.16.5.jar:git-Purpur-1082]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
... 8 more
```

[Pic of Package Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EDIt.png)
[Edit of previous question, corrected suggestion yet error persists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67427607/cannot-find-main-class-minecraft-plugin)

Comment: Looking at your screenshot of your project folder, I think the `plugin.yml` file is in the wrong location since it should be placed inside the `src` folder.  Also, check your `.jar` file to see if the main class and the `plugin.yml` file is present.

Comment: You might want to add your project structure in your IDE...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while I haven't coded a plugin but looking back at what I previously did, my `plugin.yml` isn't located in `referenced libraries` :

[image]

Also, my `plugin.yml` is a bit different from yours :

```
name: Message
main: Main.MainMessage
version: 1.0.0
author: Tom Croux - CerfMetal
commands:
  msg:
    description: Send a private message
    permission: msg.use
  r:
    description: Reply to a private message
    permission: msg.use
  mute:
    description: Mute a player
    permission: msg.use
  unmute:
    description: Unmute a player
    permission: msg.use
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `plugin.yml` inside your source folder (`src`) if you are compiling with Eclipse. If you use IntelliJ, put the file inside the `resources` folder. Your API (Spigot or Bukkit) can't load the file because it is actually not exported in your final `.jar` file. You can see if your file is exported by opening the Jar file with an archive program such as 7Zip or WinRAR. The plugin.yml should be at the root of the file.